# Call a activity inside onReceive class as background

Tags: android, android-activity

i made an alarm clock and everything works fine.

Inside public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver i have the following the working code bellow. My question is how to call an activity class to run parallel(background) with ringtone?

Also i tried the code bellow but it doesn't work:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver

{

@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm! Wake up! Wake up!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Uri alarmUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);

        if (alarmUri == null)
        {
            alarmUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        }

        Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, alarmUri);
        ringtone.play();

Intent i = new Intent(context, testactivity.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);

}
}
```

I have also create the testactivity java class

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

You can call activity inside the `runOnUiThread()` method.

e.g.

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            //your activity calling code
                        }
                    });
```

Below code is whole activity file of my project you can do the according changes in your project.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {   
                                                        
    @Override                                           
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);             
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);         
                                                        
                                                        
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {                  
            @Override                                   
            public void run() {                         
                //Your application code here            
            }                                           
        });                                             
    }                                                   
}
```